# Platform agnostic .NET Compatibility Check in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am building an MSI installer using WiX for both 32 and 64-bit systems. The package has some prerequisites that need to be checked before installing to make it easier for users to know what has gone wrong.

I have the following compatibility check for x64, but this check will actually crash the installer on a 32-bit system.

```xml
        <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck Id="netCoreStatus"
            Property="NETCORESTATUS" RollForward="latestMajor"
            RuntimeType="desktop" Version="6.0.0" Platform="x64" />
        <Launch Condition="Installed OR NETCORESTATUS=&quot;0&quot;"
            Message="[ProductName] requires Microsoft .NET 6.0 Desktop Runtime - 6.0.0 or greater." />
```

I have also tried the following, using `DotNetCoreSearch`, but while this thankfully doesn't crash the installer it ignores the `VersionNT64` condition and runs regardless of machine architecture.

```
        <netfx:DotNetCoreSearch
            RuntimeType="desktop"
            Condition="NOT VersionNT64"
            Platform="x64"
            MajorVersion="6"
            Variable="NetCoreRuntimeVersion"
        />
        <Launch Condition="VersionNT64 AND (Installed OR NetCoreRuntimeVersion=&quot;0&quot;)"
            Message="[ProductName] requires Microsoft .NET 6.0 Desktop Runtime - 6.0.0 or greater." />
```

How do I perform a platform agnostic .net check using WiX? As far as I can see the `Platform` attribute only accepts either x86 or x64.

Comment: Have you considered building an x86 MSI and an x64 MSI?

Answer (score 0):

I've given this some thought.  This is probably a WiX bug. It probably shouldn't try to do the x64 search on a x86 machine and just leave the property empty.  This is probably an edge case they didn't consider. Until this is fixed in some future version I think the only work around would be to author the x86 search but not the x64 search.  Instead use a custom action to insert a temporary record into the Wix4NetFxDotNetCheck table at installtime if VersionNT64 is true.